# what is the use of schema-element and schema-attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, schema, xslt-2.0

I am working on XSLT and came across this for priorities from the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict

I am wondering why exactly would the following be used for:

```
schema-element(E)   0.25    (matches by substitution group and type)
schema-attribute(A) 0.25    (matches by name and type)
```

why would I want to match on schema element or attribute? What is its use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

schema-element() is useful because you can match on all members of a substitution group; if you're using a schema that makes good use of substitution groups this can be very handy indeed. (But schema-attribute() is much less useful because very few schemas use global attribute declarations).

The big benefit of writing schema-aware code is that debugging is a lot easier: because the system has more information about the structure of the XML, it can give you compile-time diagnostics when you make mistakes.

For example if you write

```
<xsl:template match="schema-element(books)">
  <xsl:value-of select="books/@title"/>
</xsl:template>
```

then a schema-aware XSLT processor might well detect that the schema does not allow a valid "books" element to have a child element called "books", and it can therefore alert you to this error when compiling the stylesheet. If you simply wrote match="books", there would be no link to schema information so this inference is not possible; you would have the classic problem of working out why your stylesheet has produced no output.

There's potentially also a performance benefit, though in most cases it will be minor, and may be cancelled out by the extra cost of validating the source documents.

Comment: Could you please edit your ans and give me a small example with schema-element

Answer (score 2):

`Schema-element()` and `schema-attribute()` support schema-aware XSLT processing, which leverages type-checking to improve expressiveness and help detect bugs earlier in the development cycle.

A good introduction to the benefits of schema-aware XSLT processing is [Schema-aware processing with XSLT 2.0.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-schemaxslt/index.html)

Note that your XSLT 2.0 processor has to support schema-aware processing.  [Saxon-EE](http://www.saxonica.com/feature-matrix.html) is one example of an XSLT 2.0 processor that supports schema-aware processing.